# SQL Server: Select entry based on frequency of entries in another table

Tags: sql-server, select, greatest-n-per-group

So I am using SQL Server and I have two tables similar to the ones below:

**People**
Person ID    Name
1                  Bob
2                  Bill
3                  Barbara
4                  Bonnie

**Classes**
Person ID    Class
1                  Math
1                  Science
2                  Math
2                  English
3                  Science
3                  English
4                  English
4                  Math
4                  Science

I need to write a query that returns the name, and only the name, of the person taking the most classes. So the only result after running the query for the case above should be the name 'Bonnie'.

In the case of a tie, multiple names should be returned.

My attempt as follows:

```
`Select People.Name
from People inner join Classes 
On People.PersonID = Classes.PersonID
Group by People.Name
Having max(Classes.PersonID)`
```

The last line does not work in SQL Server, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to re-word the code to make it functional.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well your HAVING is incomplete. You would need to add something like = 4 But it also has a logical error because you don't know the PersonID. As such you don't want to look at that column. You want to look at count.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        name
FROM    (
            SELECT  name,
                    COUNT(p.PersonID) as cnt
            FROM    People p
                    JOIN Classes c
                        ON p.PersonID = c.PersonID
            GROUP BY name
        ) a
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: Yes, this helps clarify things immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC),
    P.PersonId,
    Cnt = COUNT(1)
    FROM Person p
        INNER JOIN Classes C
            ON P.PersonId = C.PersonId
        GROUP BY p.PersonId
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM Person P2
        WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE PersonId = p2.PersonId AND SeqNo = 1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL offers [ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql) that allow you to calculate the rank according to a field or aggregate.

Given these tables :

```
declare @people table (personid int primary key,name nvarchar(20))
declare @classes table (personid int ,class nvarchar(20))

insert into @people(personid,name)
values
(1,'Bob'),
(2,'Bill'),
(3,'Barbara'),
(4,'Bonnie'),
(5,'Joe')

insert into @classes (personid,class)
values
(1,'Math'),
(1,'Science'),
(2,'Math'),
(2,'English'),
(3,'Science'),
(3,'English'),
(4,'English'),
(4,'Math'),
(4,'Science')
(5,'Science')
```

The following query will calculate the person rank according to the number of classes taken:

```
select p.name,count(*) As Classes,rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as Rank
from @classes c
inner join @people p on p.personid=c.personid
group by p.name
```

Which returns Bonnie with 3 classes. All other students come second with 2 classes:

```
name    Classes Rank
------- ------- ----
Bonnie  3       1
Barbara 2       2
Bill    2       2
Bob     2       2
Joe     1       5
```

`RANK` will skip positions if there are ties. That's why `Joe` has a rank of 5.

You can't use a ranking function in a WHERE or HAVING clause. To return only the first student(s) you need to use a subquery or CTE, eg:

```
select name,classes
from (
    select p.name,count(*) As Classes,rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as Rank
    from @classes c
    inner join @people p on p.personid=c.personid
    group by p.name
) r
where rank=1
```

Or

```
;with r as (
    select p.name,count(*) As Classes,rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as Rank
    from @classes c
    inner join @people p on p.personid=c.personid
    group by p.name
)
select name,classes
from r
where rank=1
```

Both queries will return :

```
name    Classes
------- -------
Bonnie  3
```

If you want to find the N best students, you should use DENSE_RANK and return rows where the rank is less than or equal to N. With `DENSE_RANK` Joe's rank would be 3.

The following query will return students in the first two places :

```
with r as (
    select p.name,count(*) As Classes,dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as Rank
    from @classes c
    inner join @people p on p.personid=c.personid
    group by p.name
)
select name,classes
from r
where rank<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the person ID(s) with most classes with a TOP query. Then select the person's names from the people table:

```
select name 
from people
where people_id in
(
  select top(1) with ties person_id
  from classes
  group by person_id
  order by count(*) desc
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the most effective way via the `Having COUNT(*) >= ALL (Select..)` command line.
 
Code as follows:
`Select People.Name as 'Most Classes Taken:'
from People inner join Classes 
On People.PersonID = Classes.PersonID
Group by People.Name
Having count(*)>=ALL (Select count(*) from Classes group by Classes.PersonID)`